# Using pytest, can the results of a testing-function cause a further testing-function to skip?

Tags: python, pytest

My goal is to skip a test based on the outcome of a previous testing-function.
In this code-snippet, I hoped `test_zero` would make `skip_further_tests` equal to `True` & therefore `test_one` would be skipped:

```
import pytest

skip_further_tests = False

def test_zero():
    global skip_further_tests
    skip_further_tests = True

@pytest.mark.skipif(skip_further_tests, reason='a previous test failed')
def test_one():
    pass
```

`test_one` doesn't skip. Is there a way I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check variable in test body. The drawback is that this pattern means that you rely on tests execution order, which is often bad practice.

```py
import pytest

skip_further_tests = False

def test_zero():
    global skip_further_tests
    skip_further_tests = True

def test_one():
    if skip_further_tests:
        pytest.skip('Previous test failed')
    ...
```

This will result in the same results display as `skipif` decorator. Alternatively, you can write your own decorator, like

```py
# Underscore to make it look different from pytest.mak.skipif
def skip_if(var_name: str, reason: str = 'Runtime condition not fulfilled'):

    def decorator(func):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if globals()[var_name]:
                pytest.skip(reason)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    return decorator

@skip_if('skip_further_tests')
def test_one():
    ...
```